# What happened to Metapod's body after its evolution into Butterfree?

Tags: pokemon

As shown in [this GIF](https://gifer.com/en/78Mp), when Ash's Metapod evolves into Butterfree, Butterfree emerges from within Metapod, leaving a husk behind.

What happened to Metapod's body/residue? What did Ash do with it? Bury it?

Answer (score 6):

Out-of-universe, I believe the animators either simply ignored the husk or forgot about it. This was before the anime standardised Pokémon evolutions so they all looked the same, and so Metapod's evolution sticks out as an oddity. That being said, I think we *can* plausibly explain what may have happened to it.

The next time we see Ash properly, roughly 15 seconds after Butterfree's emergence, he is no longer holding Metapod's husk and is instead consulting his Pokédex. He must therefore have dropped the husk, or at least put it on the ground.

[image: Close up of Ash's upper half, he is holding the Pokédex in one hand, the other hands by his side]

A further 45 seconds later, after Butterfree saves the day by using its Sleep Powder, we see a wide shot of the area around Ash, and Metapod's husk is nowhere to be seen:

[image: 4 Beedrills lay asleep on the ground, in the background Ash jumps for joy with Butterfree next to him in the air; Misty and Pikachu stand together behind them]

The husk (which would not weigh a lot) must have simply blown away in the wind.